# Angular 4 Assigning Default Value ( Reactive Form)

Tags: angular, initialization

I am new to Angular and i am going through Angular 4 study materials for initializing default values to form control at the time of creating FormGroup.

Of course angular offers SetValue() and patchValue() for initializing the control fields, i am particular about:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
        firstName  : {value:'Naga',disabled:false},
        lastName   : {value:'R',disabled:false},
        email      : {value:'test@gmail.com',disabled:false},
        sendCatalog: {value:true,disabled:false}
    });
}
```

The issue is if i supply both 'value' and 'disabled' `{value:'Naga',disabled:false}` properties then the value 'Naga' appears in the textbox. but if i declare `{value:'Naga}` alone then the inputbox displays `[object object]`.

Is it mandatory to supply **'disabled'** as well?

Here is how i am using **get() property syntax** for returning the default value from controller to html.

assume my initialization is  for `firstName {value:'Naga'}` without 'disabled' property

```
get firstName()
{
    return this.customerForm.get('firstName').value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have actually never seen this syntax.

Could you try this ?

```
this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
  firstName  : 'Naga',
  lastName   : 'R',
  email      : 'test@gmail.com',
  sendCatalog: true
});
```

You have a second syntax that is

```
this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
  firstName  : ['Naga', [Validators.required]],
  // Others ...
});
```

That allow you to give validators to it, but I have never seen the object syntax ...

Comment: `I have actually never seen this syntax` It's time to see it) https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/test/form_builder_spec.ts#L21-L32

Comment: @trichetriche  Thank you very much for your help. The syntax what you highlighted works very well. And i can unserstand validators and custom validators goes there. But custom object syntax like key value pair i mentioned is  not working.Probably i might have made my mistake or it would not be applicable.Once again thank you very much.

Comment: @yurzui those are unit tests, do you have an example with a real form and such so that I can test it ? (or documentation so that I can write it myself ?) and no problem, glad it resolved your issue !

Answer (score 0):

if you want to assign values to formGroup when you are creating it you can do something like this.

```
 this.filterForm = new FormGroup({
  'customerName': new FormControl('user1', [Validators.required]),
  'amount': new FormControl(0, []),
  'invoicedate': new FormControl(new Date(), []),
  'phone': new FormControl('+919820412847', [])
});
```

Or if you want to set value to formGroup after data comes from API you can use

*patchValue* or *setValue* after form initialization

```
this.filterForm.patchValue({ 'customerName' : data.customerName, 'amount': data.price })
```